# Displaying label results for ListView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview, listviewitem

I have a product search textbox with a button to submit on the master page. When user click submit, the value in the textbox will be stored in Session["Search"] and the page is redirected to search.aspx. On search.aspx, the listview will search for the product and display it. Everything works except when I decided to add this

```html
if (ListView1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                lblSearch.Text = "Sorry search is not found.";
            }
```

Now when i search the product, lblSearch.Text = "Sorry search is not found." is always displayed.

Here is my code behind for Search.aspx:

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Search"] != null)
        {
            lblSearch.Text = Session["Search"].ToString();

            if (ListView1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                lblSearch.Text = "Sorry search is not found.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblSearch.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

I believe something is wrong with the ListView1.Items.Count. Also, I am using a SqlDataSource. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is the **markup** of Search.aspx:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div class="center">
        <h2><asp:Label ID="lblSearch" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="listview">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductId" DataSourceID="ProductDataSource" GroupItemCount="3">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                Search not found. Please try again.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' CssClass="productimage" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Price")) %>' />
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">
                            <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server" style=""></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Price")) %>' />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProductDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE ([ProductName] LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblSearch" Name="Search" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Post the ASP page code please, ListView1 can be empty in the page, and you're not adding any element to it

Comment: Just posted up the markup for Search.aspx @Marco Scabbiolo